# C++ change Opera proxy settings

Tags: c++, browser, proxy, opera

I'm writing an http proxy program in C++ and I need it to automatically configure the default browser proxy settings to use my proxy. With IE i can just modify the registry, Chrome has a command line parameters that can be used, firefox has the prefs file, but I can't figure out how to do it for Opera. It needs to be compatible with all versions, so PAC files are out of the question. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What about other programs? I know quite a few programs that use HTTP, e.g. to check for and download newer versions.

Comment: what do other programs have to do with the default browser?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you had problems with with IE, apparently on Windows 7 [you can't just modify the registry.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781616/c-wininet-change-proxy-settings-windows-7)

Comment: Sorry, new here. I didn't see a way to add a comment to your original post. On this one there is a clear "add comment" link that appears on mouseover.

Comment: You need to earn some more rep before you get commenting ability. +1 to get you started ;)